# How to normalize a created table with values/data?

Tags: mysql, database, migration, normalization

I have a problem in normalizing my database, I just migrated my database from excel into mySQL and it is unnormalize. How can I move the data from the old unnormalize table to the new normalize table or how can I normalize the unnormalize table?

It has like 2500 rows:

[image: sample of my table]

Comment: for one thing get the excel sheet exported to CSV. Then create a table. And use LOAD DATA INFILE. It is an [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) exploration of fixing data. It can take a while and be frustrating

Comment: I think you can use SQLyog such kind of tool. Which actually imports data from Excel to MySQL with the help of ODBC driver.

Comment: What are your key drivers to normalize that table? Just for running queries quickly on a 2,5 K table you do not need normalization at all - not even indeces... What I am saying is: the degree of normalization usually depends on what you want to do and what you have (e.g. in terms of RAM and RAM utilization)